# Plotting error in Python

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot a simple function in python ( x + sqrt(x^2 + 2x) ). Here is my code:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import math
X = np.linspace(-999999,999999)
Y = (X+math.sqrt(X**2+2*X))
pl.plot(X,Y)
pl.show()
```

Here is the error that I am facing: 
TypeError: only length -1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Answer (score 1):

use

`Y = [(x+math.sqrt(x**2+2*x)) for x in X]`

or

`Y = map(lambda x: (x+math.sqrt(x**2+2*x)), X)`

to generate a list of y-values.

You can also vectorize your function and apply it. See [List comprehension, map, and numpy.vectorize performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703310/list-comprehension-map-and-numpy-vectorize-performance) for additional remarks.

Comment: why not `Y = X+np.sqrt(X**2+2*X)` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that the math.sqrt function expects a single number as an input. Since you have a numpy-array with more than one element you should use the built-in numpy function sqrt as suggested by Rory Yorke i.e.

```
Y = X+np.sqrt(X**2+2*X
```

Since the numpy function is much more optimized it gives you a better performance,
for example:

```
X = np.arange(10000)
timeit Y = map(lambda x: (x+math.sqrt(x**2+2*x)), X)
10 loops, best of 3: 82.1 ms per loop
timeit Y = X+np.sqrt(X**2+2*X) 
10000 loops, best of 3: 108 µs per loop
```