# Vectorizing CONDITIONAL logic in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

Old-school c programmer trying to get with the times and learn Python. Struggling to see how to use vectorization effectively to replace for loops. I get the basic concept that Python can do mathematical functions on entire matricies in a single statement, and that's really cool. But I seldom work with mathematical relationships. Almost all my for loops apply CONDITIONAL logic.

Here's a very simple example to illustrate the concept:

```
import numpy as np

# Initial values
default = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
# Override values should only replace initial values when not nan
override = [np.nan,np.nan,3.5,np.nan,5.6,6.7,np.nan,8.95] 

# I wish I knew how to replace this for loop with a single line of vectorized code
for i in range(len(default)):
    if(np.isnan(override[i])==False): #Only override when override value is other than nan
        default[i]=override[i]

default
```

I have a feeling that for loop could be eliminated with a single python statement that only overwrites values of `default` with values of `override` that are not `np.nan`. But I can't see how to do it.

This is just a simplified example to illustrate the concept. **My real question is whether or not vectorization is generally useful to replace for loops with conditional logic, or if it's only applicable to mathematical relationships, where the benefits and method of achieving them are obvious.** All of my real code challenges are much more complex and the conditional logic is more complex than just a simple "only use this value if it's non-nan".

I found hundreds of articles online about how to use vectorization in Python, but they all seem to focus on replacing *mathematical calculations* in for loops. All my for loops involve conditional logic. Can vectorization help me or am I trying to fit a square peg in a round hole?

Thanks!

Comment: I think @EliadL's answer is good and it illustrates why "it depends" on whether you should vectorize. You will often get a performance boost from vectorization -- i.e. your code will run faster. However, there is something to be said for readability. For me, the original `for` loop in your code is more readable and understandable. OTOH you get into the habit of using numpy every day, then maybe `np.where` looks completely normal and you get a benefit of speed and readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing's first, the vectorized version:

```py
override_is_not_nan = np.logical_not(np.isnan(override))
np.where(override_is_not_nan, override, default)
```

As for your real question, vectorization is useful for multiprocessing.
And not just for multi-core CPUs.
Considering today's GPUs have thousands of cores, using tensors with similar code can make it run much faster.
**How much** faster? That depends on your data, implementation and hardware.
Evidently, the combination of vectorization with GPUs is part of what enabled the huge progress in the field of Deep Learning.

Comment: Thanks so much. But my REAL "real question" is how to learn about this. You knew exactly how to use np.where to achieve THIS PARTICULAR solution. I'm really struggling to absorb the much bigger picture of how to write vectorized code in LOTS of situations. All the articles I can find online are about mathematical relationships. Any ideas how/where to learn to "think vectorized"? Thanks!!!

Comment: @eriktownsend To a large extent it's like learning a new language if you are coming off from a non-vectorized wired mindset. So, just practice and force yourself to avoid loops! NumPy as an enviornment that has those vectorized ufuncs, tools, etc. gives us an easy way to do so, once you get past the syntax(which is easy again with the docs).

Comment: I was first introduced to vectorization while learning MATLAB in a CS course. See [some examples here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/array-comparison-with-relational-operators.html). Later I ran into it again in two of Andrew Ng's courses online: [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/machine-learning/vectorization-WnQWH) and [Deep Learning](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/neural-networks-deep-learning/vectorization-NYnog) (linked to relevant videos, they're freely available). With `numpy`, I improved the more I used and googled it or read the docs.

Comment: Thanks so much for this info. Super helpful!

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is usually the preferred *one line* alternative to `for` loops in Python. It is possible to throw in a conditional into the comprehension as well.

In this specific case we iterate over elements of `default` and `override` by zipping them together and replace values of `default` according to the conditional check.

```
>>> [y if not(np.isnan(y)) else x for (x,y) in zip(default, override)]

[1, 2, 3.5, 4, 5.6, 6.7, 7, 8.95]
```

To answer your broader question about vectorization and speedups, the answer unfortunately is *it depends*. There are situations where a simple `for` loop performs better than its vectorized counterparts. List comprehensions for example, is just for improving the readability of code as opposed to providing a serious speedup.

The answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703310/list-comprehension-map-and-numpy-vectorize-performance) question address this in more detail.

Comment: Fun fact: `np.nan` fails self equality, ie. `np.nan == np.nan` returns `False`. So you can also replace the code with `[x if y==y else y for (x,y) in zip(default, override)]`

Answer (score 0):

First find the indices where the non-nan values are located.
Replace the values as indices in the `default` array with `override` array values.

```
import numpy as np
np_default = np.array(default).asdtype(float) # Convert np_default to numpy array with float values
non_nan_indices = np.where(~np.isnan(override)) # Get non nan indices
np_default[non_nan_indices] = np.array(override)[non_nan_indices] # Replacing the values at non-nan indices
np_default # Returns array([1.  , 2.  , 3.5 , 4.  , 5.6 , 6.7 , 7.  , 8.95])
```

Vectorization is where numpy comes to your help it takes the advantage of typed natured of array which result in much faster operations. See  [[BlogPost]](https://datadiscuss.com/proof-that-numpy-is-much-faster-than-normal-python-array/) for detail.