# Using arithmetic on numpy structured array elements?

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

Lets say that I have a structured numpy array like this:

```
x = np.array([(1, 1.5), (2, 5.21)], dtype=[('foo', 'i4'), ('bar', 'f8')])
```

What I want to do is be able to add and scalar-multiply these structured array elements together much like you would a numpy vector. E.g. something equivalent to `2 * x[0] + x[1]` gives me a structured array element that looks like `(4, 8.21)`.

Of course, simply adding the array elements together doesn't work, nor does passing them into a ufunc like `np.add()`, I assume because its not technically an array, just a scalar that contains multiple values packaged together.

I know that this would be very easy to do algorithmically, but in my case these array elements actually get pretty large, so I would like to do this in as 'numpyic' of a way as possible for any of the optimization it grants me. Is there any numpy functionality that lets me do this?

Comment: I don't think you can. The only way from what I've found so far is to loop through all of the elements separately, which is a hit on performance. Vectorization works *because the data type of the entire array is the same* and is a numeric array. Because the type of each value in an element in your structured array can be of a different type and precision, I don't think it's possible to take advantage of any NumPy vectorization. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66107179/numpy-broadcasting-and-structured-dtype-how-to-handle-a-vector-as-an-entity

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah you're probably right. I just figured that since every value is always being added to the corresponding value in a structurally similar element, numpy wouldn't need to worry about finding where each value is located in memory, since its always in the same place, just in the next element. To what degree is that completely not how it works? I instinctively just tend to trust any built in functionality more than anything I write myself.